# Xcode 6 fails to detect device in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I recently upgraded to Xcode 6 and I'm starting to get strange crashes when loading viewcontrollers in AppDelegate.
I found for example that this line of code:

```
BOOL isIphone = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone;
```

...didn't always return YES when I was running the app on simulator for iPhone5! Therefore the app tried to load an iPad nib with a crash as result.

Now I only do my testing on the actual device. But can someone please tell me how xcode/simulator can make such a misstake? And how you can protect yourself from it.

Comment: Can you please post some more code and what exact error you are getting when crash occurred.

Comment: Rather than reporting that [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone is returning NO, can you let us know what you see being returned by [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]?  What version of iOS are you seeing this with?  8.0?

Answer (score 0):

Up to the last beta of Xcode6, I was having very odd issues with the simulator. In my case, anything network related would refuse to work after a while, perhaps after computer has gone to sleep and was subsequently woken up. One thing that worked was to restart the simulator (surprise surprise!). Give it a go.